# Template Parameter variable / Dynamic Instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, overloading

I am an absolutely beginner in C++, so I really would appreciate your help!

I am currently implementing a Matrix Class with Template Parameters for datatype, dimension width and dimension height.

```
template <class T, int rows, int columns> class Matrix
```

In the multiplication function I have to create the result matrix (Height Matrix A x Width Matrix B), but I receive the error "template value cannot appear in a constant expression".

```
// overload * for matrix multiplication 
   template <class T, int rows, int columns>
   Matrix<T, rows, columns> operator*(Matrix<T, rows, columns> a, Matrix<T, rows, columns> b) {
     Matrix <T, rows, columns> result = new Matrix<T, a->height, b->width>;
// make multiplication here
```

Any ideas how to make a new Matrix with the given type and the height from A resp. width from B?

Thank you so much!

Comment: First you might want to review your matrix multiplication rules.  For example, an (r1,c1) matrix times an (r2,c2) matrix requires c1 == r2, and gives an (r1,c2) result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot set static (compile time) "fields" from dynamic (run time) values.

You could (**not saying you should**) use different template parameters for the sizes of your two matrices and create a new matrix with them :

```
template <class T, int rows_A, int columns_A, int rows_B, int columns_B>
Matrix<T, rows_A, columns_B> operator*(Matrix<T, rows_A, columns_A> a, Matrix<T, rows_B, columns_B> b) {
    Matrix <T, rows_A, columns_B> result;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

And as Joe Z. says, you'll also have to check the validity of the operation before. Because `columns_A` must be equal to `rows_B`, you can factorize the two template parameters.

EDIT : mmmmmmm wrote this factorization in below comments :

```
template <class T, int rows_A, int columns_A_rows_B, int columns_B>
Matrix<T, rows_A, columns_B> operator*(
    Matrix<T, rows_A, columns_A_rows_B> a,
    Matrix<T, columns_A_rows_B, columns_B> b
) {
    Matrix <T, rows_A, columns_B> result;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Yet ,this code is not really good looking, neither easy to use. If you can, you could try the idea of making the sizes dynamic (not parameter templates), as suggested by Matt.

Comment: But the matrices sizes are not specified, so it could be any number of things. Is there any way to just create a new Matrix without columns/row parameter? Maybe something like a template specialization, could that be a possible solution?

Comment: Templates are not a way to express an infinity of possibilities. They are on the code, but not when the program is running. The precise values of rows and columns are defined during the compilation of the program. If the size of the matrix is not "defineable" during compilation, you should give up the idea of using templates for that. Also, don't forget each combination of T/rows/columns will generate a new unique class definition using your template. If the sizes of you matrices vary widely, templates may be risky for your application.

Comment: I don't really see what you could do with template specialization, because you would have to specialize each possible T/rows/columns combination yourself... Huge code for nothing less that proving that templates shouln't be an ideal solution ;)

Comment: I receive an error "shadows template parameter". How exactly must I implemented the code snippet provided by @RüdigerStevens? How does the compiler know the values for "int rows_A, int columns_A_rows_B, int columns_B"?

Comment: It's up to you to set it in your code during template class instanciation : ` Matrix<10, 5> A ; Matrix<5, 8> B ; Matrix<10, 8> C = A*B;`. This code will create a definition for operator*() with rows_A = 10, columns_A_rows_B = 5 and columns_B = 8.

Answer (score 1):

How about make rows and columns as the parameters of the constructors?

```
template <class T> class Matrix
{        
public:           
   Matrix(int rows, int columns)
   {....}    
}
```

//then you can create a new instance with:

```
 Matrix <T>* result = new Matrix<T> (a->height, b->width)
```

Comment: But I have to use templates, is there any other way by using templates?

Comment: @Patrick I don't think there's another way. Template instantiation happens during compilation, not during runtime, so if you pass a variable, the compiler cann't decide what the type is at the compile time, that's question here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of two different concepts when referring to your template class Matrix that stores the data of the matrix and the *operator which is a template method.

If you think of the *operator as a template method that multiplies template classes, then you realize that you need more template arguments and that those arguments are only partial given by one instance of the matrix class.

The error is given because a->width and a->height a not know at compile time and every template argument has to be known at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

It is looks like in this line:

```
Matrix <T, rows, columns> result = new Matrix<T, a->height, b->width>;
```

Is error. You are trying to write new Address to variable which is declared on stack.
Try this:

```
Matrix<T, int, int> *result = new Matrix<T, a->height, b->width>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, the g++ compiler says:

    matrix.h:68:23: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, int rows, int columns> class Matrix’
     Matrix<T, int, int> *result = new Matrix<T, a->height, b->width>();

Comment: Now I see, thats my fault. If someone trying to run this code: please dont do it. @Patrick thanks for info. There should be: Matrix<T> *result = new Matrix<T>(a->height, b->width);